# Enable payment gateway for Particular products - Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

I want to enable the payment gateway for some products Only.  On my website, I have cash on delivery & other payment gateways. Cash on delivery should be enabled for every product.

For that i created a attribute called payment gateway in product section . It is drop down attribute with yes & No as value . So this attribute now visible in product side . When we adding or editing a product we can see this attribute .

Please help on the following .

Now in checkout page i have to check the product in checkout have enabled the payment gateway . If yes then only i need to show the payment gateway , other wise it should be cash on delivery . How can i do this ?

Please help.

Comment: You need to create this functionality either custom or you can purchase extension which is available on the market. Like this, https://store.webkul.com/magento2-multi-vendor-payment-method-restrictions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to either enable or disable certain payment methods based on some criteria you can use the `payment_method_is_active` event.

In the `payment_method_is_active` event you have access to 3 parameters:

- `$observer->getEvent()->getData('method_instance)`, the payment method
- `$observer->getEvent()->getData('quote')`, the quote being processed
- `$observer->getEvent()->getData('result')`, a data object containing the result

In the result `is_available` is defined which is either `true` if the payment method should be enabled ("available") or `false` if it should be disabled.

With these 3 objects you can

- Determine whether the payment method is the method you want to disable based on some criteria
- Get the products in the quote and their attributes
- Result to say whether the payment method should be enabled or not.

```php
class DisablePaymentMethodBasedOnSomething implements ObserverInterface {
    public function execute($observer) {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $method = $event->getData('method_instance');
        $quote = $event->getData('quote');
        $result = $event->getData('result');

        if (payment method is not cash on delivery) {
            return;
        }

        if (quote does not contain products with gateway attribute) {
            return;
        }

        $result->setData('...', false);
    }
}
```

As you see I didn't fill in all the blanks, I hope the example will guide you in the right direction.

Comment: Hi Julian , could you please tell where i have to put this code ?

Comment: also could you please help me to get my custom attribute value of the cart products in the loop

Comment: I recommend learning a bit more about events and observers within Magento, otherwise you will most definitely run into numerous problems trying to implement this. In case of "get my custom attribute value of the cart products", this can be done through the `$quote` object which is available to you in the event. Using this quote object you can get the products that are in your quote (cart) and thus their attributes.